# Mockito matchers | Correct Usage

Tags: junit, mockito

Mockito provides a lot of matchers like any(), anyClass() etc.

People can debate on their usage. But I feel that matchers should be used when we don't really care about what the input object contains as long as it is of the expected class.

I just want to know if this usage is correct? If not, what is the better way to use them?

For example:

Say we have a test that expects a Runtime Exception, when a method is called with some request object. Since we explicitly throw a runtime exception here when the mock is called, it does not matter what the request object's contents are. So this test seems logical.

```
@Test(expected = RunTimeException.class)
public void testExceptionOccurs() {
  when(mock.method(any(RequestObject.class))).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

  mock.method(new RequestObject());
}
```

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that allowing *any object of a given type* is a great use for Matchers, and that you're calling matchers correctly, but the code isn't doing what you're describing.

In Mockito 1.x, `any(RequestObject.class)` *will not actually check the type of the parameter*. Its behavior is identical to `anyObject()`, except that previous to Java 8, the Java compiler couldn't infer a generic type specified as a parameter. **Instead, use `isA(RequestObject.class)` to check types.**

---

Mockito's default behavior is to check argument equality—specifically equality using `equals` (or `==` for primitive types). I've found `any` (and `anyInt` etc) to be the most valuable, because they ignore an argument entirely for the purposes of matching, but there are plenty of reasons that you'd want to override that `equals` behavior with Matchers:

- To only check an argument's type, using `isA`.
- To check instances more specifically than `equals` is defined for, like checking for *referential equality* using `same`.
- To check properties of arguments, like that a passed bean has a certain value for one of its properties.
- To reuse Hamcrest matchers via `intThat`, `argThat`, and so forth.

Final note: make sure that if you're using matchers or captors anywhere in your list of arguments, that you use one for each and every argument in that call. [Mockito needs that 1:1 mapping.](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html)

---

**UPDATE:** Mockito committer [Brice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48136/brice) has offered [some historical background and future direction](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/55631479):

> For historical reference, `any` is a shorthand alias of `anything`, at that time the API was forcing one to cast, and contributors and/or commiters thought about passing the class as a param to avoid this cast, without changing the semantic of this API. However this change eventually modified what people thought that this API was doing. **This will be fixed in mockito 2+**

Comment: isn't it better to always use `isA` rather than `any`?

Comment: @Templar Definitely not "always": `isA` [rejects null](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/matchers/InstanceOf.java#L22), which may not be necessary or desirable. More importantly, Mockito syntax favors flexibility-by-default, to reduce test brittleness in response to refactors and other changes; it is typically unlikely that a parameter value will have a _relevant type but irrelevant value_ (where `any` would cover a wholly irrelevant parameter, and other matchers would cover a relevant value).